How do I use LUKS encrypted partitions with Kubuntu 24.04 installation?
I am trying to install Kubuntu 24.04 with manual partitioning. I have created primary partitions for EFI and boot, and an encrypted partition with logical volumes for swap, root, and home.

Previously, after this step I just run the Kubuntu installer, manually assigned /dev/mapper/vg0-* partitions for root, home, and swap, as well as the primary partitions for /boot/efi and /boot, and it all worked ok.
But in Kubuntu 24.10 the installer changed, and now I'm not sure what I should do. There are separate dropdown items for the whole disk and for the mounted logical volume, and the installer suggests that I should format the logical volumes to use them, and then tries to delete them for some reason.

It all ends with this error:

Is there any way to solve this? Maybe I do not need to manually partition the disk prior to running the installer? Could I achieve what I want just using the dialogs within the installer itself?

24.10 or 24.04? Another approach is to just run a standard/minimal install and then migrate it over to the structure you actually wanted.

@frostschutz thank you, 24.04 definitely)
I'm not sure how to migrate to a new partitioning structure after the installation. Seems to be even more complex and potentially error-prone.
I decided to install 23.04 and then upgrade to 24.04. But that's impossible too for now, only new installs are permitted. But hopefully that's a matter of weeks.

23.04 is EOL, 23.10 should work until July 2024, otherwise 22.04 LTS should continue to work, if you don't mind upgrading after installing.

I actually found a solution and was able to perform an installation.
I created and mounted my luks volumes (with luksOpen), and after that formatted all of them with mkfs / mkswap.
The key to success was to name the luks device (when opening it) to live-WHATEVER, so that it appears under /dev/mapper/live-WHATEVER.
Also, before starting the installation, I run the command while true; do vgchange -ay; done (it should stay running in terminal while the installation is performed).
Not sure if any one of those would be enough, but as a result, my luks partitions were not unmounted during the installation, and I was able to successfully install the system on them.
I found this solution on Calamares github issues, not sure if I'm allowed to post links here, but I hope this attribution is enough.

this solution didn't work for me in Ubuntu: does kubuntu use different installer?

@morgwai Kubuntu 24.04 LTS uses the calamares installer (as three flavors use), which yes differs to ubuntu-desktop-installer used by Ubuntu Desktop and in fact most flavors. The calamares installer can use LUKS2

Boot into a live environment, and configure your /boot and LVM/luks or luks/LVM the way you'd like.
Then start the installer and choose your existing partitions.
Sometimes you need to run boot-repair to get a bootable system.

Ubuntu 24.04 has a new installer, which no longer displays existing LUKS/LVM/mdadm, so you can't choose them. You can do it with 22.04 LTS, and then upgrade...
